# Having trouble with while loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, methods, while-loop

Code below has 2 methods: `BetAmount` takes the user input. `Multiplier` takes `BetAmount` and based on the image being true/false returns the multiplier. For instance, if `BetAmount` is 10 and all images are true then `Multiplier` should return 30.

In the `okButton_Click` method, the label should continue to show the result as long as totalAmount > 0. If all images are false and I enter 10 in the text box, the loop should subtract 10 from totalAmount until totalAmount = 0. Initially, totalAmount = 100. Think of it as a slot machine, you lose money if the images are not true.

```
protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool imageOne = true;
        bool imageTwo = false;
        bool imageThree = false;
        double totalAmount = 100;
        double winAmount = Multiplier(imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree);
        double result = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (winAmount > 0)
            {
                result = totalAmount + winAmount;
            }
            else
            {
                result = totalAmount - BetAmount();
            }

            resultLabel.Text = result.ToString();            
        }

    }
    protected double BetAmount()
    {
        double betValue = double.Parse(numTextBox.Text);
        return betValue;
    }
    protected double Multiplier(bool firstImage, bool secondImage, bool thirdImage)
    {
        double multiplier = BetAmount();

        if (firstImage == true) multiplier *= 1;
        if (secondImage == true) multiplier *= 1;
        if (thirdImage == true) multiplier *= 1;

        return multiplier;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Every time I enter the value 10 in the text box, the page continues to load and I don't see any result. I have noticed IIS Express Worker Process has pushed my CPU performance to almost 100%. I wonder if that is causing the issue.

Comment: Why do you think the loop will stop when `totalAmount` equals `0`? There is no exit condition for the loop specified, just `while(true)`. Why not `while (totalAmount > 0)`?

Comment: `multiplier *= 1` does not change the value of `multiplier`. It just multiplies it by `1`.

Comment: My goal is to create a slot machine application. I have been able to create a Reel which shows three random images. If one of the images is Cherry, totalAmount should increase by the bet amount. If two cherries, betAmount is multiplied by 2 and added to the totalAmount. If images show no cherries, then totalAmount should subtract the bet amount.

Comment: Why are you using a loop in the button click event?

Comment: Rufus L - I am new to programming. I am not sure how I can fix the code. I agree while loop should be while (totalAmount > 0) but I am not sure about the rest,

Comment: You have your logic clear? Can you explain the logic you tried to implement in code? Did you debug the code and check if the code works as per your logic?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a number of commenters are observing, you don't appear to have fully thought out what you want to do, your "business rules" if you will. That should be the first thing to get down. I'll start here:

> My goal is to create a slot machine application. I have been able to create a Reel which shows three random images. If one of the images is Cherry, totalAmount should increase by the bet amount. If two cherries, betAmount is multiplied by 2 and added to the totalAmount. If images show no cherries, then totalAmount should subtract the bet amount.

With this, and some educated guesses from your code, I get this:

1. User begins with 100 credits.
2. User bets a specific amount and "pulls lever."
3. One cherry pays even, two cherries pays double, three pays triple. No cherries loses bet.
4. Once the user runs out of credits, he's busted.

Now, some educated guesses about how you are attempting to implement these "business rules," i.e. your "functional specifications":

1. Total remaining credits are displayed in a label.
2. User enters a bet amount in a text box.
3. User clicks an "Ok" button.
4. Your reel displays your three random images.
5. Winnings are calculated, and added to/subtracted from the total remaining credits.
6. Total remaining credits display is updated.
7. If user runs out of credits, game is over.

Now, your code has a few problems:

1. Every time you push the "Ok" button, the user gets a fresh 100 credits. Your totalAmount variable needs to be outside your event handler and accessible to it.
2. The process that you use to calculate the winnings doesn't belong in a while loop. (Let alone an endless while loop, as you have here.) You only want to do the calculation once every time a user clicks the Ok button, so you only have to do it once in the code.
3. As a number of people have mentioned, multiplying your multiplier by 1 has no effect and is therefore superfluous.

Now, probably the best way to handle your multiplier is to start it at 0, and every time you get a hit add 1 to it. Then, return BetAmount * multiplier. Like so:

```
int multiplier = 0;

if (firstImage == true) multiplier++;
if (secondImage == true) multiplier++;
if (thirdImage == true) multiplier++;

return multiplier * BetAmount();
```

You'll also need to add in the logic to prevent the user from betting more credits than he has, and to end the game when he runs out.

There's more, but that should get you on track.

Comment: Feel free to help me out by explaining why this is a bad answer, if you are voting it down.

Comment: BobRodes - Thank you for your help! Thank you for breaking my project into steps. I am getting very close to completing the project and my last hurdle is to solve on how to add winnings or subtract losses from the total 100 credits.

Comment: int balance = 100; //Need to fix the code here because it resets to 100.

        protected int PlayerBalance()
        {           
            if (CalculateWinAmount() > 0)
            {
                balance += CalculateWinAmount(); //CalculateWinAmount returns winning bets
            }
            else
            {
                balance -= BetAmount(); 
            }          
            return balance;
        }
        protected void DisplayPlayerBalance()
        {
            playerTotalAmountLabel.Text = PlayerBalance().ToString();
        }

Comment: @Amit Look at number 1 of the "few problems" I mentioned. Hint: every time you click the Ok button, you call okButton_Click(). (And what happens to totalAmount every time you call okButton_Click()?)